# Fullcalendar Event Not showing

Tags: fullcalendar, svelte

Trying to get a single event to show on FullCalendar

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  import {
    Calendar,
    type EventApi,
    type EventDropArg,
  } from "@fullcalendar/core";
  import interactionPlugin, {
    type EventResizeDoneArg,
  } from "@fullcalendar/interaction";
  import resourceTimeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/resource-timegrid";
  import luxon2Plugin from "@fullcalendar/luxon2";
  import scrollGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/scrollgrid";
  import { millisecondsToTime } from "../utils/time";
  // Import other necessary plugins and styles if needed
  import { createEventDispatcher } from "svelte";
  import { CalendarEvent, type SelectionInfo } from "../types/event";
  import { roundTo } from "../utils/common";
  import type { CalendarResource } from "../types/calendar";

  export let resources: CalendarResource[];
  let calendar: Calendar;
  let dragging = false;
  let resizing = false;
  let events = [];
  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

  const eventContent = (arg: EventApi): { html: string } => {
    let htm = CalendarEvent.fromEventApi(arg.event).innerHTML;
    console.log(htm);

    return {
      // @ts-ignore
      html: htm,
    };
  };

  const fetchResources = (
    _fetchInfo: any,
    successCallback: any,
    _failureCallback: any
  ) => {
    resources = [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "monday",
        businessHours: [
          {
            startTime: "00:00",
            endTime: "23:00",
            daysOfWeek: [0, 2, 3],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "tuesday",
        businessHours: [
          {
            startTime: "00:00",
            endTime: "23:00",
            daysOfWeek: [0, 2, 3],
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
    successCallback(resources);
  };
  const eventDragStart = () => {
    dragging = true;
  };

  const eventDragStop = () => (dragging = false);

  const eventDrop = (eventInfo: EventDropArg) => {
    const { event, newResource, revert } = eventInfo;
    saveEvent(event);
    dispatch("eventDrop", {
      id: +event.id,
      updateData: {
        happeningOn: event.start?.toISOString(),
      },
      revert,
    });
  };
  const eventResizeStart = () => (resizing = true);

  const eventResizeStop = () => (resizing = false);
  const eventResize = (eventInfo: EventResizeDoneArg) => {
    const { event, revert } = eventInfo;
    const startDate: Date = event.start || new Date();
    const endDate: Date = event.end || new Date();
    const duration = millisecondsToTime(
      roundTo(endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime(), 90000)
    );

    dispatch("eventResize", {
      id: +event.id,
      updateData: {
        duration,
        happeningOn: startDate.toISOString(),
      },
      revert,
    });
  };
  const select = (selectionInfo: SelectionInfo) => {
    const { start, end, resource } = selectionInfo;
    const { id, title } = resource?._resource || {};
    const newEvent = {
      resource: {
        id,
        title,
      },
      start,
      end,
    };
    saveEvent(newEvent);
    dispatch("eventSelect", {
      start,
      end,
      resource: {
        id,
        title,
      },
    });
  };
  const saveEvent = (event: any) => {
    // Retrieve existing events from local storage
    const existingEvents = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem("calendarEvents") || "[]"
    );

    // Add the new event to the existing events
    existingEvents.push(event);

    // Save the updated events array to local storage
    localStorage.setItem("calendarEvents", JSON.stringify(existingEvents));
  };
  onMount(() => {
    // Set your New Zealand timezone
    const nzTimeZone = "Pacific/Auckland";

    // Initialize the calendar
    calendar = new Calendar(document.getElementById("calendar")!, {
      locale: "en",
      timeZone: nzTimeZone,
      plugins: [
        interactionPlugin,
        luxon2Plugin,
        resourceTimeGridPlugin,
        resourceTimeGridPlugin,
        scrollGridPlugin,
      ],
      initialView: "resourceTimeGridWeek",
      headerToolbar: {
        start: "today,prev,next",
        center: "title",
        end: "resourceTimeGridWeek,resourceTimeGridDay",
      },
      scrollTime: null,
      selectable: true,
      selectMirror: true,
      selectOverlap: false,
      unselectAuto: false,
      allDaySlot: false,
      slotDuration: "00:30",
      snapDuration: "02:30",
      dayMinWidth: 120,
      slotLabelFormat: {
        hour: "2-digit",
        minute: "2-digit",
        omitZeroMinute: false,
        meridiem: "short",
      },
      editable: true,
      resourceOrder: "title",
      resources: fetchResources,
      // Event handlers
      datesSet: handleDates,
      events: fetchEvents,
      eventContent,
      eventClick,
      eventDragStart,
      eventDragStop,
      eventDrop,
      eventResizeStart,
      eventResizeStop,
      eventResize,
      select,
      eventAllow: (dropInfo, draggedEvent) => {
        return true;
      },
    });
    calendar.render();
    calendar.refetchEvents();
  });

  function handleDates(arg: any) {
    // Handle dates set event
    console.log("Dates set:", arg);
  }

  // Other event handling functions...
  const destroyEvents = () => {
    if (events) events.forEach((event: CalendarEvent) => event.destroy());
  };
  function fetchEvents(
    _info: any,
    successCallback: (events: any[]) => void,
    _failureCallback: any
  ) {
    // Hardcoded event data
    const eventsData = [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "Hardcoded Event",
        start: "2023-11-29T06:15:00",
      },
    ];
    // return eventsData;
    // Call the successCallback with the hardcoded event data
    successCallback(eventsData);
  }

  function eventClick(arg: any) {
    // Handle event click
    console.log("Event clicked:", arg);
  }
  const renderCalendar = () => {
    if (calendar) calendar.refetchResources();
  };
  $: {
    if (resources)
      // update calendar every time resources change
      renderCalendar();
  }
</script>

<div id="calendar"></div>
```

For some reason, it appears as though the event is reaching the calendar, because it doesnt let me drag over the time, but the event doesnt show. Also when i put a console log in eventContent nothing logs, but when i drag on calendar to create a event it does log. Im not sure where the event is getting lost. Or if it may be due to a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using [resourceTimeGridWeek](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-view) as the default view, which is a resource-aware view, you won't see the event you've added because you didn't give it a `resourceId` matching one of the resources in the calendar. Therefore, fullCalendar doesn't know where to display it - that view doesn't have an area for events which don't belong to a resource.

For example you could write:

```
const eventsData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Hardcoded Event",
    start: "2023-11-29T06:15:00",
    resourceId: 1
  },
];
```

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resources-and-events for more information